# Updating form control from another thread using events

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I'm a novice coder, so excuse me if this sounds like a silly question. I have checked on SO and googled around for a good explanation of how to update a form's controls (i.e. listview, label) from another thread/class without freezing the form and without exposing the form to the other class (aka subscribing to events). I haven't found anything yet that solves my problem or that was explained thoroughly.

Here's what I have so far, but the UI still freezes when it's updated...

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UIEvents.CounterChanged += UpdateCounterLabel;
    }

    public void UpdateCounterLabel(string text)
    {
        lock (lblCounter)
        {
            try
            {
                if (lblCounter.InvokeRequired)
                    lblCounter.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => lblCounter.Text = string.Format("[{0}]", text)));
                else
                    lblCounter.Text = string.Format("[{0}]", text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And DoWork() is called from a second thread:

```
public static class UIEvents
{
    public static event UpdateCounterHandler CounterChanged;
    public delegate void UpdateCounterHandler(string text);

    public static void UpdateCounter(string text)
    {
        if (CounterChanged != null)
            CounterChanged(text);
    }
}

public static class Worker
{
    public static void DoWork()
    {
        int result;
        ...
        ..
        .
        UIEvents.UpdateCounter(result.ToString());
    }
}
```

So where am I going wrong?

Comment: How many times per second do you call `UpdateCounterLabel`? Perhaps, you should throttle it. Also, use `BeginInvoke` rather than `Invoke`, if you can.

Comment: This is called multiple times per second (maybe 10-20 depending on thread count). I've never used BeginInvoke...what benefit does it have over Invoke?

Comment: anyone? even if you can point me in the direction of a good tutorial, that's fine.

Comment: My bet is that you call `Invoke` on a tight loop from the worker thread and thus clog the UI thread message loop. Try `BegingInvoke`, it's asynchronous, and use `Stopwatch` inside your worker thread to update the UI no more than 24 times per second. The eyes of the user won't be able to track more frequent updates anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up putting a 100ms timeout between every UI update and it solved the issue.